# I'm stuck with this.. (number 9,6 and 3)

Tags: analysis

### Hello guys/girls I was bored and I just played around with math. I am stuck and it's about raised numbers. (9, 6 and 3)

So this is how you calculate it. (same method for all numbers)

1. Raise 3, 6 and 9 each from 1 to 10.
2. If the product is more than one digit then add up the digits until there is only one digit.
3. Look at the result...

**Number 3.**

3^1 = 3

3^2 = **9**

3^3 = 27 = 2+7 = **9**

3^4 = 81 = 8+1 = **9**

3^5 = 243 = 2+4+3 = **9**

3^6 = 729 = 7+2+9 = 18 = 1+8 = **9**

3^7 = 2187 = 2+1+8+7 = 18 = 1+8 = **9**

3^8 = 6561 = 6+5+6+1 = 18 = 1+8 = **9**

3^9 = 19683 = 1+9+6+8+3 = 27 = 2+7 = **9**

3^10 = 59049 = 5+9+0+4+9 = 27 = 2+7 = **9***

**Number 6.**
I'm not gonna write plus signs now, because I think you've got the Idea

6^1 = 6

6^2 = 36 = **9**

6^3 = 216 = **9**

6^4 = 1296 = 18 = **9**

6^5 = 7776 = 27 = **9**

6^6 = 46656 = 27 = **9**

6^7 = 279936 = 36 = **9**

6^8 = 1679616 = 36 = **9**

6^9 = 10077696 = 36 = **9**

6^10 = 60466176 = 36 = **9**

**Number 9.**

9^1 = **9**

9^2 = 81 = **9**

9^3 = 729 = 18 = **9**

9^4 = 6561 = 18 = **9**

9^5 = 59049 = 27 = **9**

9^6 = 531441 = 18 = **9**

9^7 = 4782969 = 45 = **9**

9^8 = 43046721 = 27 = **9**

9^9 = 387420489 = 45 = **9**

9^10 = 3486784401 = 45 = **9**

So to my question, why is the sum 9 for number 3 and 6 and not only for the 9 itself? 
I know that 3, 6 and 9 is relative to each other but i'm still confused. (3+6+9 = 18 = 1+8 = 9)

And is there an equation for this? 
Thanks for reading :)

Comment: “I was bored and I just played around with math.”  +1 for that.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines and http://mathlair.allfunandgames.ca/digroots.php and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigitalRoot.html

Comment: If you get an answer for $3$ and $6$ you'll also have an answer for $9$ because $9^x = 3^{2x}$.

Answer (score 1):

any number of the form :

$3^n$ for $n \ge 2$,

$6^n$ for $n \ge 2$,

$9^n$ for $n \ge 1$  is divisible by 9.

If a number is a multiple of 9, then its digit sum is 9. It is a easy result which you can prove.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is not $9$ for $3^1$ and $6^1$  Any multiple of $9$ will have the sum of digits a multiple of $9$, so when you get to one digit it will be $9$.  Then $3^2$ and $6^2$ (and all higher powers) have a factor of $9$, so will reduce to $9$.  You can see [Wikipedia on divisibility rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule)

Comment: Of course most of us know the solution to Luce's observation.  But aren't we sort of destroying Luce's fun *to play with math* when we provide Luce with a complete solution?  Let Luce discover the insights by his/her own by only giving vague hints.  Otherwise we would spoil the game.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe:  But Luce did ask the question specifically.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I like your thinking, didn't even think about that :)
But still, RossMillikan Thank you very much for the answer, really helped :)